# Multiple binaries with the same name

Tags: environment-variables

If I have two executable files with the same name on $PATH, how does Ubuntu decide which one to use when it is run in the terminal?

For example, my Ubuntu originally had python installed at /usr/bin/python. Recently, I installed Anaconda's distribution of python, which has its own binary installed at /home/karnivaurus/anaconda/bin/python. Then, in my .bashrc file, I entered:

```
export PATH="/home/karnivaurus/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

So both binaries are now on PATH. But if I run python in the terminal, it always uses the original installation, rather than Anaconda's version. Why is this?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `command -v python` and the output of `ls -lab /home/karnivaurus/anaconda/bin`

Answer (score 1):

In order to optimise command lookup, bash keeps a cache, per bash process, of where it found files. So if you typed `python` and it found it in /usr/bin/, then changing the PATH to provide another python earlier in the PATH will have no effect. You need to also give the bash command:

```
hash -r
```

to forget the optimised cached.  See `help hash`. (Of course, I assume you reread the .bashrc or set the PATH explicitly in your shell as well).